# List directories with given name recursively with Java

Tags: java, apache-commons

I want to collect all (sub-)directories within directory matching a given name using Apache IO Commons. While I can solve this task for files using a `NameFileFilter` in combination with `FileUtils.listFiles`, I can't find a solution to do this for folders.

I tried the following snippet:

```
IOFileFilter fileFilter = new NameFileFilter(fileName);
Collection<File> fileList = FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(rootFolder, fileFilter, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
```

It identifies folders and subfolders, but does not filter them according to the NameFileFilter. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code only looks for files with this name, not for any directories.

This should work:

```
IOFileFilter nameFilter = new NameFileFilter(fileName);
Collection<File> fileList = FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(rootFolder, 
  new NotFileFilter(TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE),
  nameFilter);
```